# Typescript seperate files for internal modules VSCode vs WebStorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am writing a NodeJS application and am having some problems with my editor.
Is there a reason the following works in WebStorm but not VSCode?

Edit: I didn't realize this first as I was quickly testing it, WebStorm's intellisense finds the class, but then the compiler fails and says it can't find it.

```js
// one.ts
module Core.Routes {
  export class BaseRoute {}
}

// another-one.ts
module Core.Routes {
  class User extends BaseRoute {}
}
```

I am trying to organize my code so that I can store routes in different files,
but still inherit features from the base route.

In WebStorm this works fine, however in VSCode it is unable to find the module.
Is there something I have to do differently for VSCode?

I am basing it on the example in the video [here](https://youtu.be/_bpGKu89YMg?t=584).
In the video Visual Studio is being used, but I am on Linux and I really want to give VSCode a shot.

I have the following as my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message you are getting from the compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. In Node every file is a module. So you can't really specify the same module across files like that. Even if Webstorm intellisense can find the class name, the actual code wouldn't work. It's different from front-end Typescript

This would be a working solution:

```
//baseRoute.ts
export class BaseRoute {}
```

And then

```
//user.ts
import {BaseRoute} from "./baseRoute"
class User extends BaseRoute{}
```

Comment: In Typescript you can have modules spread out across multiple files.

Comment: @SunilD. I think that's true for client-side typescript, not Node.